# One-time and Recurring donations with PayPal

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, donations

I need to implement PayPal donations for a non-profit organization (which has a "Personal" account and would like to keep it as Personal) for two scenarios: one-time pay, and recurring donation. The user can select a predefined amount or type a custom amount.

I've found a solution for a Business account so far, by using [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/) for one-time pay (using Orders API) and recurring donations (using Subscriptions API) by rendering custom button using their SDK. I've used vanilla Javascript on the frontend, and Laravel on the backend.

I'm wondering is there a way to do the same with a "Personal" account? Or do we need to upgrade the account to Business? Any better ideas?

Comment: Why not have them make a second, business account?

Comment: Not sure, as I heard it's a bit complicated. So you think it isn't possible to achieve this without using a Business account?

Answer (score 1):

They should use a business account to receive payments, not a personal account. No exceptions. And no downsides to switching to a business account.

As for implementation, an extremely basic 'Donate' button created via https://www.paypal.com/buttons may meet your needs. Under the new buyer interface where available, it has an option the user can check to make the donation recurring.

Implementing the Subscriptions API is only necessary if you need (and want) much more responsibility and control over what is going on. I would definitely avoid the time and expense of implementing the Subscriptions API,if a basic Donate button meets at least 95% of what you need.